# The term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, powershell-3.0

We have recently installed SharePoint 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2.
When I am trying to run Enable-SPSessionStateService -DefaultProvision using Windows PowerShell then below error is occuring. 
What am I missing here?? Please help.

```
PS C:\Users\sysuser> Enable-SPSessionStateService -DefaultProvision
Enable-SPSessionStateService : The term 'Enable-SPSessionStateService' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-SPSessionStateService -DefaultProvision
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-SPSessionStateService:String) [],     CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Are you running this from the Sharepoint Management Shell? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878(v=office.15).aspx#section2

Comment: I guess it worked using SharePoint Management Shell because when  I ran it it didn't give any error but also not any success message,previously I ran using Windows PowerShell. Can you please help me to understand why there are SharePoint Management shell and windows powershell and which one should use. Many Thanks...

Comment: SharePoint Management Shell is an enhanced version of Windows PowerShell with the SharePoint libraries preloaded.  You can run SharePoint commands from Windows PowerShell, you just have to load the SharePoint libraries manually.